# Maintain decimal points with 0 in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, decimal, decimal-point

My requirement is to maintain the decimal value with 0. Here I have mentioned the sample object below.

```
let sampleObject = {
    "firstname": "Sundar",
    "lastname": "J",
    "salary": 10000.00,
    "incentive": 6500.50,
    "age": 25
}
```

I need to display salary and incentive without losing the decimal places even the decimal value as 0. But after parsing this JSON object, decimal point with 0 will be lost. Is there any possibility or work around to do this?

Comment: If you want to have your number stored in a specific format, you need to store it as a string. For all JavaScript (and by extension TypeScript) are concerned, `100 and 100.00` are the same number.

Comment: you can use `toFixed()` method or  `toLocaleString()` method

Comment: Two common workarounds are to either store the decimal values as a string, or multiply them by an appropriate power of 10 to lose the decimal when storing, and dividing by that same value when retrieving.  In your case, you'd store salary and incentive as an integer representing pennies.